# GridView edit mode without objectdatasource

Tags: asp.net, data-binding

Is is possible to force Grid view edit mode without using object data source, I set EditIndex, but the Edit template is never shown till I change the binding to ObjectDataSource

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if you mean such an example but I hope it will be helpful:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" OnRowEditing="GridView1_RowEditing" 
    OnRowUpdating="GridView1_RowUpdating" 
    onrowcancelingedit="GridView1_RowCancelingEdit">
    <Columns>
        <asp:CommandField EditText="Edit" UpdateText="Update" ShowEditButton="true" />
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lbl" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txt" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Code Behind:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            GridView1.DataSource = ItemRepo.GetItemList();
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }
    protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
        GridView1.DataSource = ItemRepo.GetItemList();
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
    protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
        GridView1.DataSource = ItemRepo.GetItemList();
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
    protected void GridView1_RowCancelingEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
        GridView1.DataSource = ItemRepo.GetItemList();
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
}

class Item
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
class ItemRepo
{
    public static List<Item> GetItemList()
    {
        List<Item> list = new List<Item>();
        list.Add(new Item() { Name = "Item1" });
        list.Add(new Item() { Name = "Item2" });
        list.Add(new Item() { Name = "Item3" });
        list.Add(new Item() { Name = "Item4" });
        list.Add(new Item() { Name = "Item5" });
        return list;
    }
}
```

I think your problem can be not databinding the gridview after setting editindex.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean to set [Edit-Mode as default](http://forums.asp.net/t/1087061.aspx)? Because you have to databind your gridview, otherwise there are no items to show.